# How to start a program hidden from Windows taskbar?

Tags: windows, shell

How can I start a program hidden from the Windows taskbar?

I want to start the task manager minimized at login automatically so that I can see the CPU load in the system tray.

Comment: You mean it should run but not show up the Windows task bar?

Comment: Yes, because I only want to see it in the system tray.

Comment: Please don’t clarify your question in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in [Run a program hidden in Windows 10](https://winaero.com/blog/run-a-program-hidden-in-windows-10/) this can be done with a `VBScript` that looks like

```
Dim WShell
Set WShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WShell.Run "taskmgr.exe", 0
Set WShell = Nothing
```

Saving this script as `hiddentaskmgr.vbs` will provide a script that starts the task manager hidden from the taskbar.

It will still be running in the background and create an icon in the system tray showing the CPU load. This script can also be used in the Windows startup folder.